# IdHTTP XML, getting xml, help please

Tags: xml, delphi, delphi-2010, msxml, idhttp

I can not get through IdHTTP XML document from the site. I always had the answer 403 / HTTP 1.1 and text/html (need text/xml)

When using MSXML all well and getting XML file. But I need a proxy, so need idhtop. When using the synapse does not change.

**Work with msxml:**

```
CoInitialize(nil);
     GetXML:={$IFDEF VER210}CoXMLHTTP{$ELSE}CoXMLHTTPRequest{$ENDIF}.Create;
     GetXML.open('POST', '***************', false, EmptyParam, EmptyParam);
     GetXML.setRequestHeader('Host', '***************');
     GetXML.setRequestHeader('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.13) Gecko/20101203 Firefox/3.6.13');
     GetXML.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
     GamesBody:='***************';
     GetXML.send(GamesBody);
     Form1.Memo2.Lines.Text:=GetXML.responseText;
     ResultPage:=GetXML.responseText;
     if Pos('error code', ResultPage)=0 then
     begin
    CoUninitialize;
```

How to set up IdHTTP? All settings have changed 100 times Or a connection to a proxy MSXML?

Comment: So, could you elaborate your POST request ? What you're sending in the `GamesBody` ? Are you using secured connection ? What kind of proxy authentication are you using (if any) ?

Answer (score 0):

MSXML uses MSIE (Windows Internet Epxlorer) which has settings for proxy. You can try TWebBrowser to get it - it is also part or MSIE, and probably also has proxy set my Windows admins.

Using synapse or idHTTP you have to set proxy manually.

`HTTP 403` suggests that you failed to specify correct login/password for proxy. Or that NTLM authorization is used. Read the document you got along HTTP 403 error - it can contain useful hints.

So all in all:

1) Consult you Windows Administrators what proxy settings are required and what authentication modes are supported.

2) Press `retag` button and add proper tag for your given version of Delphi

3) Press edit link and add the proxy settings told you by admins (login and password you can replace with some random texts) and also add the idHTTP code you tried to connect via proxy.

4) Download latest Indy sources. Indy 10 told to have troublesome in Microsoft NTLM proxy mode and Indy 9 probably do not support NTLM at all.

Sample NTLM Proxy code: http://bredcompmaniak.blogspot.com/2010/09/ntlm-indy-10.html